# Templates or css skins for the asp.net membership login control?

Tags: asp.net, css

I want to style the asp.net membership login control and I am too lazy to handcraft a professional looking one.

I couldn't find ready made css styles for the login control. Are there any available on the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be extend the look of your current style sheet.  More than likely any style sheet found on the web would look out of place in the context of your site.

That being said if you want a clean looking starting point with a lot of good built in styles take a look at [Google Blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) specifically their [form demo page](http://www.blueprintcss.org/tests/parts/forms.html).